# Save UITextView Text Linked to Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, save, uitextview

I am making an iPad app, it currently has multiple UITableViews named like so:

monTable, tueTable, wedTable etc...

I would like to have a UITextView which is editable. Then any text when the user leaves the text view it saves the chunk of text and is linked to the cell selected in the table. So when that cell is reselected the text for that cell is shown.

So two sections to this question:

How can I save chunks of text from a UITextView?

How can I show this data when selecting the correct cell?

Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're just starting out with your iPhone programming. I would strongly suggest you change your data model to core data, and then build your uitableviews from objects retrieved from core data managed objects. It'll make your life so much easier in the long run.

As for your question. When you are editing your tableviews, on Save, you would update your data model for that uitableviews and then reload the uitableviews using [myTable reload].

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Comment: Hi I have taken a look at set up my project using CoreData but how can I save the data dependant on the date selected, and then load it back in depending on the day selected?